# select multiple files in django with single  filefield

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, django-admin

How can I select multiple files in a single fileField in django? I want to select different file formats  in a single filefiled in django admin.

```
**models.py**
 class FileModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=settings=PATH)

**admin.py**
 admin.site.register(FileModel,FileAdmin);
```

In the admin I want to customize the file field to select multiple files to store in given path? Could you please help me?

Comment: You can't do this, you might consider a separate model to represent single files and create a manytomany relationship with your FileModel

Comment: @ChrisPratt Really don't see the problem with wanting to attach multiple files to a model. Why have a FileField at all when you can have a one to one relationship to a custom FileModel? Anyway. Someone else was also surprised by this limitation: http://koensblog.eu/blog/7/multiple-file-upload-django - worth a look?

Answer (score 4):

You can't? The FileField was not designed for that purpose.

You would have to define your own field (possibly extended from FileField) that pickles the internal data (paths to multiple files) and stores them in the database and unpickles them back.

Of course, I don't see a reason to do this at all, when you can simply define one to many relationship or even many to many relationship between a new filelist model and existing filemodel. Then you could make an inline admin handler attached to the uploader model and you can add multiple files easily that way.

See [inline admin models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for details.

Comment: I think we can do it using Jquery plugin by customizing django admin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Django, this is now possible.

See the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it comes up at the top of Google search so I thought I'd comment. You can use [django-multiupload](https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload) to do this.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from multiupload.fields import MultiFileField

class UploadForm(forms.Form):
     attachments = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=3, max_file_size=1024*1024*5)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I try this solution and gives me the error:
`Django Version:  1.8.5
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  'list' object has no attribute '_committed'`
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I didn't have much luck with this - it appears to be a dead project without support for newer versions of Django.