# Django multiple files upload only returns the last file

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am trying to post multiple files from a form to my django view. However, only the last file that was uploaded is posted.

Html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% load bootstrap %}
    {{form|bootstrap}}
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="myfiles[]" multiple>
    <div id="upload_prev"></div>
    <button type="submit">{% trans "upload_lesson_plan" %}</button>
</form>
```

python:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('myfiles[]')
print(files)
```

Output:

`[<InMemoryUploadedFile: name_of_last_image>]`

Any idea how to fix this? I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're try to upload multiple files with a single InputFile it won't work. You will only recieve the last selected file. You need an InputFile for each one.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% load bootstrap %}
    {{form|bootstrap}}
    <input type="file" id="upload1" name="myfiles[]">
    <input type="file" id="upload2" name="myfiles[]">
    <input type="file" id="upload3" name="myfiles[]">
    <div id="upload_prev"></div>
    <button type="submit">{% trans "upload_lesson_plan" %}</button>
</form>
```

You may want to try [django-multiupload](https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload) Which says in its description allow multiple file upload with a single input file.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979790/select-multiple-files-in-django-with-single-filefield)

Comment: I have done exactly what the django docs say. It does not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks but not really. Your solution uses multiple input fields.